# Alternate between windows on launcher click

Tags: unity, window

There is no way to set unity to change between opened windows by clicking on the laucher incon?
Everytime I want to change a window of the same program I have to use the keyboard!

Answer (score 1):

There is not, exactly. It will focus that application. If you click it while that application is focused though, it should show the zoomed out view of all the application windows and you can click on another that way.

Comment: But my ubuntu 12.04 does not show the zoomed out view of all the application windows focused. Is necessary some extra configuration to the unity do this?
Thank you for the answer.